# Error while parsing datetime array of JSON message into c# via Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, datetime, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json library to parse JSON message in c#

```
string json = @"{'SomeSchedule': [
      {
        'PeriodEnd': '2014-05-28',
        'PeriodStart': '2014-02-28',
        'ResetDate': '2014-05-26',
        'PayDate': '2014-05-28'
      },
      {
        'PeriodEnd': '2014-02-28',
        'PeriodStart': '2013-11-29',
        'ResetDate': '2014-02-26',
        'PayDate': '2014-02-28'
      },
      {
        'PeriodEnd': '2014-12-01',
        'PeriodStart': '2014-08-28',
        'ResetDate': '2014-11-26',
        'PayDate': '2014-12-01'
      },
      {
        'PeriodEnd': '2014-08-28',
        'PeriodStart': '2014-05-28',
        'ResetDate': '2014-08-26',
        'PayDate': '2014-08-28'
      }
    ],
    }";
```

Data class:

```
    public class Data
    {
        public DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime PeriodStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ResetDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime PayDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Parsing

```
 JObject dataObject1 = JObject.Parse(json);
        var plan = dataObject1["SomeSchedule"].ToObject<IList<Data>>();
```

I'm not able to read all DateTime fields correctly. When the above code is run, we can see the value in plan variable. I'm able to read ResetDate and PayDate, but PeriodEnd and PeriodStart are not read correctly. It is returning a default date "1/1/0001".

Can anyone please let me know what i am doing wrong In above code?

Answer (score 2):

Change property names to match data in json:

```
public class Data
{
    public DateTime PeriodEnd { get; set; } // instead of PeriodEndDate
    public DateTime PeriodStart { get; set; } // instead of PeriodStartDate
    public DateTime ResetDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayDate { get; set; }
}
```

Or use `JsonProperty` attribute to map your properties:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("PeriodEnd")]
    public DateTime PeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PeriodStart")]
    public DateTime PeriodStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ResetDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PayDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ohh...OMG..how i haven't seen this. Thank you so much for your help.